# Secure Input Validation in Bash/Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sanitization

I'm writing a bash script that requires several pieces of user input, primarily directory paths and file names. The program will create the specified directories and files.

When writing the directory path, I request the absolute path - **~/DIR/...**, or **$PATH/DIR/...** or **./DIR/...** are not allowed. Directory paths should only be provided in the form of **/DIR/DIR/...**, file paths in the form **/DIR/DIR/.../filename**, and file names in the form of **filename**.
I also want to assure the user has not added any command-line options (for example, if I run **sudo**, I want to assure that the user has not appended **-u** anywhere in their statement) to their input.

However, I'm not entirely certain of the best way to sanitize their input, since directory paths and filenames may contain dashes, underscores, spaces, periods, and alphanumeric characters. Any other character should be detected.

User input is gathered through **read**. I'm using an Ubuntu system, so as long as it complies with Ubuntu shell then it'll work.
Assume that only the default system packages are installed.

Multiple options are acceptable to handle individual sections of validation (e.g. using `--` to treat following data as a parameter and not a command [suggested by Siguza], and then another option for handling directory paths).

Absolute paths are required for correct mapping of directory structure. Any other format of path would cause the program to incorrectly interpret the structure when matched or appended to other paths, due to the functions I'm performing on the strings of paths.

Thank you.

---

What worked: I used the accepted answer, using **realpath** in some situations and **readlink**, and using **--** to interpret the following text as parameters. If you want to allow relative paths, then use the result of readlink or realpath as your path. If you want to disallow relative paths, then compare the original string to the result of readlink or realpath.

Comment: Most commands support the `--` option, which makes them treat all following parameters as arguments, and not options/flags. Apart from that, enclose all variables in double quotes to avoid expansion.

Comment: While that does take care of the first two problems, it still remains that the user can entire directory paths in a format my program cannot accept. I either need to reject invalid input, or conform it to valid input.

Comment: Re: "the user can entire directory paths in a format my program cannot accept. I either need to reject invalid input, or conform it to valid input": *Or* you can change your program to accept such formats . . .

Comment: @LoganHartman: I'm not sure what you mean by "make the script more complex for absolutely no gain". Your whole question is asking for help in making the script more complex for the purpose of rejecting paths you don't support; how is that any better than simply supporting them?

Comment: @LoganHartman: But anyway, if you have legitimate reasons for restricting your inputs, you should explain them in the question. It's possible that your reasons will map to known solutions. (For example, "I need a path that can safely be passed to the `foo` utility" might be answered with, "oh, there's a special `check_path_for_foo` utility that can do that safety-check for you.)

Comment: @LoganHartman: `mkdir`, `cd`, and `cp` don't have any restrictions on the filenames they accept; what made you think they did? Re: "I am matching them against static full paths": What kind of comparison do you need? Note that two paths can both be absolute, and be completely different, yet point to the same file. So, please put aside your mistaken scruples, and edit your question to add the relevant details about what you actually need.

Comment: Literals with `~/DIR` or `$DIR` or whatnot, if you're quoting correctly, won't be expanded before they're passed to your `mkdir` or `cp` or whatever, so if you don't have a filename with `~` or a `$` in it, it'll just come up not-found. Is there a reason you can't just handle that error when it occurs?

Comment: To be clear: Valid pathnames on UNIX can typically [POSIX doesn't mandate this, but almost every major UNIX filesystem allows it] contain **literally any non-NUL character, including newlines**. Your `while read` is thus quite buggy: Filenames with backslash literals have them stripped (unless doubled up); trailing whitespace is removed by the `read` command itself if IFS isn't cleared; and if an entry *does* end in a backslash, `read` takes it to mean that the line *after* it is part of the same entry!

Comment: ...now, if you were handling a NUL-delimited input stream, you could represent all possible inputs with `IFS= read -r -d '' path`, or if you wanted to support any character other than a newline, `IFS= read -r path`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This script may be ran on both UNIX filesystems and filesystem shares (SAMBA, etc.) and as such need to assume some kind of conformity, hence why I'm ignoring some characters. After reading your comments, I've modified the code I'm using to validate/expand paths to account for such situations.

Comment: Gotcha! Given that use case, might I suggest you use the POSIX portable filename character set as a minimum baseline? That provides a minimum baseline below which any filesystem is out-of-compliance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if [this character set](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxa400/bpxug469.htm) is what you're talking about, that is essentially what I'm using, only with the addition of the space character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e    

while read path; do
    result=`realpath -m -- "$path"`
    if [ "$result" != "$path" ] && [ "$result/" != "$path" ] ; then
        echo "Rejected: $path"
    else
        last_char_index=$((${#path}-1))
        last_char=${path:$last_char_index:1}
        if [ "$last_char" == "/" ]; then
            echo "New directory: $path"
            mkdir -- "$path"
        else
            echo "New file: $path"
            touch -- "$path"
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```

I use `realpath` to catch relative paths, then *always* use user input between double quotes to avoid commands injection (if any is possible).
I guess there are better ways of doing but at the moment that's all I can think of.

Edit: as advised in the comments, I added `--` to ensure the file/directory names are safely given to `touch`, `mkdir` and `realpath`.

Comment: Quoting variables does not prevent them from being parsed as options. Use `--` for that.

Comment: @Siguza Could you please provide an example where this script isn't safe?

Comment: I never said it was exploitable, but you could set path = `-X` and have realpath crash on an invalid option. You should also `set -e;`, otherwise you could set path = `''` and, since error messages are printed to stderr and not stdout, realpath would crash, but the `else` block would be executed. Again, not exploitable, but probably undesirable.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try this once I am home and see if it will work.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer, because with a little variation it did work. I didn't use the "set" part, because I individually check each command for the exit status, in order to show the user what the status code was if the program failed. While 'realpath' works in some situations, I've found that 'readlink -f' works better in others. @yoones Thank you.

Comment: In general, the `read -r` argument should be used unless you have a very good reason to skip it. As it is, this will treat backslashes in input as syntactical.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. I didn't catch that; I just changed it accordingly in my code.

Comment: Oh -- and I note that `==` is being passed to `[ ]`; that should be reserved for `[[ ]]`, as it's a bash extension not present in the POSIX standard for the `test` command; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html, specifying `=` as the string comparison operator.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Whoops. Didn't catch that either. Really shouldn't be writing scripts late at night. Thank you, again.